# How do I implement docusign for angular2 App?

Tags: docusignapi, docushare

I would like to implement sending signature request and signing the documents. Do you know if it is very difficult to do this? Can you please give me the resource to access DocuSign api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official documentation : REST API Recipe: Request a Signature via Email](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/request-a-signature-via-email) gives great examples on how to send signature request for different languages. I recommend you look at the Node.js example :

```
var url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
var body = "";  // no request body for login api call

// set request url, method, body, and headers
var options = initializeRequest(url, "GET", body, email, password);

// send the request...
request(options, function(err, res, body) {
    if(!parseResponseBody(err, res, body)) {
        return;
    }
    baseUrl = JSON.parse(body).loginAccounts[0].baseUrl;
    next(null); // call next function
});
```

Comment: https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeViews&operations=createRecipient&mode=basic  --> i am not getting signature option of after redirected to the generated url . i am getting signature option only if i use url from incoming e-mail request to review and sign.

Comment: Are you trying to implement remote or embedded signing ? Can you post your code ? That would be helpful in order to help you for this issue

Comment: yeah, i have tried embedded signing on api explorer only . we got  dynamic 5-minutes active url  but that url is having my pdf but there is no sign in option .

Comment: I'd recommend that you attach your code as well as some screenshots of the issue you are seeing.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Jo8ulDC.png -> i got url but it is not having sign option. i did any code . i just using api only

Comment: Did you make sure that the user was created a Tab for him/her to sign ? (see [Tabs documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154178/discussion-between-dharan-g-and-frederic).